# How to add a value describing from which link a value came from in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a following code

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['site.com']
    start_urls = ['site.com/a',
                  'site.com/b'
                 ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': "data.csv", 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}

    def parse(self, response):

        name = response.css('.name::text').extract()
        price = response.css('.price::text').extract()
        
        row_data = zip(name, price)
        
        for item in row_data:
            
            scraped_info = {
                'name': item[0],
                'price': item[1],
            }

            yield scraped_info

        next_page = response.css('ul.pager::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                 response.urljoin(next_page),
                 callback=self.parse
            )
```

Code works fine and outputs a csv file like this

```
# name price
# A    1
# B    2
```

But I would like to add a third value that would describe from which of the start_urls data came to look like this:

```
#name price source
#A    1     site_a
#B    2     site_b
```

It would be ideal if the source wasn't the URL since it goes over multiple pages and the URL changes like so: site.com/a then site.com/a/1 etc.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by the source not being the url, the data is coming from an URL. Do you mean wanting just the pagination part of the URL as the source ? Do you have an explicit example of how you want the source to look like with respect to the url the data comes from ? response.url gives you the url scrapy is getting a response from. You can manipulate the url string to get it how you want, but without a bit more information it's hard to inform you.

Comment: Then I would like for the response.url to give only part of the URL, because it would give out something like this site,com/a/lots_of_things/1 and I would like to shorten it to just be site.com/a if that's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scrapy docs [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.url) we can find how to get the url of the response scrapy gives us. Always good to get used to looking up the scrapy docs, the more you read of it, the easier it gets to look things up.

It's within the response object. You can select all sorts of different parts of the response. The most basic would be `response.url` which the docs tells you it's a string. You can also select the body of the response, headers etc...

Following from the comment. You essentially just need to manipulate the string. The split string method can split the url up into parts split by '/' and you can select the first two items of that list.

```
for item in row_data:
        
        scraped_info = {
            'name': item[0],
            'price': item[1],
            'source': response.url.split('/')[:1]
        }
```

Remember you'll have to put source as one of your fields within items.py though.

Comment: Well that's surprisingly easy, thank you very much! I'm new to scrapy and still on pretty basic level as can be clearly seen

Comment: Don't worry about it! You'll keep learning bit by bit. It's a big framework with lots of moving parts. I'm still learning every day looking at the scrapy docs.

Comment: I've just edited the post to include the docs part to this learning point. Keep reading the docs, it can be abit overwhelming at first, but the longer you stare at it and keep writing code the easier it becomes to use it. The section you need to concentrate on this question is the response and request part of the docs. Has everything about handling responses in scrapy as well as any part of making a request using scrapy.

Comment: Thanks again! They will be very very useful